# The class of function $C=\{f-g \mid f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are convex$\}$ is dense in the function space of $C([a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

The class of function $C=\{f-g\mid f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are convex$\}$ is dense in the function space of $C([a,b])=\{$all continuous functions between $[a,b]$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Here the topology is induced by the norm $\Vert f \Vert =\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$

My idea: My teacher gave us a hint that we first need to prove that $C$ is closed under the lattice operation $\vee$. This can be achieved if we note the fact that $(a_1-b_1)\vee(a_2-b_2)=(a_1+b_2)\vee(a_2+b_1)-(b_1+b_2)$. Then I do think the Baire category theorem should be applied because this theorem is essential when proving another similar proposition, that is, the class of continuous functions which are nowhere differentiable is dense in the function space of $C(\mathbb{R})$. Now, what we have to do is to construct a series of nowhere dense closed sets $E_n$, whose union $\bigcup\limits_{n\geq1}E_n=C(\mathbb{R})\backslash C$. And what confuses me is how to use the hint given by my teacher to construct $E_n$.

Any hint or solution is highly appreciated!

Comment: You need a topology on $C(\mathbb R)$ for this question to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is a subset of $C([a, b])$ and satisfies the conditions of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem:

- $C$ separates points, i.e. for $x, y \in [a, b]$ with $x \ne y$ there is an $f \in C$ with $f(x) \ne f(y)$.
- $C$ contains the constant function $1$.
- If $f \in C$ and $a \in \Bbb R$ then $af \in \Bbb R$.
- If $f, g \in C$ then $f+g \in C$ and $f \vee g \in C$.

The last condition is what you verified according to the given hint. All other conditions are easy to verify.

The [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Lattice_versions) then states that $C$ is dense in  $C([a, b])$ with respect to the topology of uniform convergence.